# sums of divisors mod 9

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am wondering when a number of the form: $49+504\cdot n$ where $n$ is an integer, will be both a perfect square and also have $\sigma (n) = 0 \mod 9$ and $\sigma (n) = 1 \mod 8$ where $\sigma (n) $ is sum of divisors function

Comment: Since $49 + 504n = 7*(7 + 72n)$, and you want a perfect square, 7 must divide the second factor evenly.  Therefore $n$ must be divisible by 7.  That might help pare things down a smidge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a^2=49+504n$

$a^2=7(7+72n)\quad [1]$

$7|\text{rhs of } [1]\Rightarrow 7|a^2\Rightarrow 7|a\Rightarrow \exists b\in\Bbb{N}|7b=a$

$(7b)^2=7(7+72n)$

$49b^2=7(7+72n)$

$7b^2=7+72n$

$7b^2-7=72n$

$7(b^2-1)=72n\quad [2]$

$7|\text{lhs of } [2]\Rightarrow 7|n\Rightarrow \exists m\in\Bbb{N}|7m=n$

$7(b^2-1)=72(7m)$

$b^2-1=72m$

$b^2=72m+1 \Rightarrow$ ($b$ is odd)

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\text{If } b\equiv\space\pmod{72}&\text{then } b^2\equiv\space\pmod{72}\\ \hline
1&1\\ \hline 
3&9\\ \hline 
5&25\\ \hline 
7&49\\ \hline 
9&9\\ \hline 
11&49\\ \hline 
13&25\\ \hline 
15&9\\ \hline 
17&1\\ \hline 
19&1\\ \hline 
21&9\\ \hline 
23&25\\ \hline 
25&49\\ \hline 
27&9\\ \hline 
29&49\\ \hline 
31&25\\ \hline 
33&9\\ \hline 
35&1\\ \hline 
37&1\\ \hline 
39&9\\ \hline 
41&25\\ \hline 
43&49\\ \hline 
45&9\\ \hline 
47&49\\ \hline 
49&25\\ \hline 
51&9\\ \hline 
53&1\\ \hline 
55&1\\ \hline 
57&9\\ \hline
59&25\\ \hline 
61&49\\ \hline 
63&9\\ \hline 
65&49\\ \hline 
67&25\\ \hline 
69&9\\ \hline 
71&1\\ \hline 
\end{array}$

The chart above indicates that $b^2\equiv 1\pmod{72}\iff b\equiv 1,17\pmod{18}$

Therefore $\exists c\in\Bbb{N}|18c+1=b \text{ or } 18c+17=b$

After the substitutions of $a$ with $7b$ and $b$ with $18c+1$ or $18c+17$ we get the result:

$$a^2=7^2(18c+1)^2 \text{ or } a^2=7^2(18c+17)^2$$

Every natural number can be expressed as the product of powers of unique primes $(p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}p_3^{e_3}...p_s^{e_s})$. By using this expression the sum of factors of $a^2$ can be obtained with the following formula:

$\sigma(a^2)=\prod_{r=1}^s\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}$

(Note all $e$'s in $a^2$ are even)

each $\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}$ term in $\sigma (a^2)$ has one of four outcomes $\pmod8$ {$1,3,5,7$}

$\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}\equiv 3\pmod8\iff$

$ (p_r\equiv 1\pmod8$ and $e_r\equiv 2\pmod8)$ or $(p_r\equiv 5\pmod8$ and $e_r\equiv 6\pmod8)$

$\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}\equiv 5\pmod8\iff$

$ (p_r\equiv 1\pmod8$ and $e_r\equiv 4\pmod8)$ or $(p_r\equiv 3\pmod8$ and $e_r\equiv 2\pmod4)$or $(p_r\equiv 5\pmod8$ and $e_r\equiv 4\pmod8)$

$\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}\equiv 7\pmod8\iff$

$ (p_r\equiv 1\pmod8$ and $e_r\equiv 6\pmod8)$ or $(p_r\equiv 5\pmod8$ and $e_r\equiv 2\pmod8)$

In any other case $\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}\equiv 1\pmod8$

Count the number of $\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}$ terms that are in each of the three categories {$3,5,7$}$\pmod8$

$\sigma(a^2)\equiv 1\pmod8\iff$

The number of $\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}$ terms in the three $\pmod8$ categories are all even or all odd.

$\sigma(a^2)\equiv 0\pmod9\iff$

One of the $\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}$ terms is divisible by 9 or two of the $\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}$ terms are divisible by 3 ( but not 9).

$9|\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}\iff$

$ (p_r\equiv 1\pmod3$ and $e_r\equiv 8\pmod{18})$

$3|\frac{p_r^{e_r+1}-1}{p_r-1}\iff$

$ (p_r\equiv 1\pmod3$ and $e_r\equiv 2\pmod{18})$ or

$(p_r\equiv 1\pmod3$ and $e_r\equiv 14\pmod{18})$

Comment: that is a beautiful answer

Comment: @argamon Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As commented n must have 7 as a factor. For $\sigma(n)  ≡0 \mod 8$ we have:

$n=7k$  ⇒ $N=49+72\times 7^2 k=49(1+72\times k)$

We must have:

$1+72\times k=t^2$  ⇒ $72\times k=(t+1)(t-1)$

if $t+1=72$ then $t-1=70$ and $k=70$  ⇒ $N=7^2\times 71^2$

you may find more solutions such as $k=35$ ⇒ $N=7^2\times 35^2$

For $\sigma (n) ≡1\mod 8$ we must find k such that $\sigma(n)≡1\mod 8$ and follow similar algorithm to find N.  We have:

$7 ≡-1\mod 8$

So we must have:

$k ≡-1\mod 8$

But in this case $n=7k$ is odd and it's sum of divisors is even so the condition $n ≡1\mod 8$ can not be made. Moreover if $k=7^{2s-1}$ or $n=7^{2s}$, then $\sigma (n) ≡1 \mod 8$; hence we must have:

$1+72\times 7^{2s}=t^2$

May be brute force helps to find t.